# how to use perl Git::Repository module to conduct equivalent of "git push -u origin master"?

Tags: git, perl

I am using Perl's Git::Repository module to perform git operations.
I am stuck at performing the equivalent of the following:

```
git push - u origin master
```

Comment: For my own work, I found this module to be so low-level that it doesn't add anything for me over doing it in straight Perl.

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to achieve this using the following:

```
$r->run ( 'push', '-u' => { origin => 'master' } );
```